# Nonparametric CDF and pdf through the np package in R

Tags: r, smoothing

I'm using the `np` package in `R`, and I would like to use the nonparametric distribution function `npudist` as for instance we normally use the `ecdf` function.

```
set.seet(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
Fn <- ecdf(x)
Fn(.4)
# [1] 0.78
library(np)
Fn2 <- npudist(x)
Fn2(.4)
# Error in Fn2(.4) : could not find function "Fn2"
```

As you can see `npudist` computes the distribution for each x point, and it does not return a function. However, the necessary information is stored in `Fn2` because when we compare

```
plot(Fn)
plot(Fn2)
```

it is clear that `Fn2` is the smoothed version of `Fn`. Because I need to use this in an integration, I would like to have (the pdf and) the CDF as a functions rather than data.frames. Any help? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
dist = npudist(x)
cdf <- function(x) predict(dist, edat = x)
dens = npudens(x)
pdf <- function(x) predict(dens, edat = x)
```

Obtaining:

```
cdf(0.4)
pdf(0.4)
```

The right values are obtained. You can check via:

```
plot(cdf); abline(v = 0.4, lty = 2); abline(h = cdf(0.4), lty = 2)
plot(pdf); abline(v = 0.4, lty = 2); abline(h = pdf(0.4), lty = 2)
```

You can also integrate with this set-up if desired:

```
integrate(f = pdf, lower = -Inf, upper = 0.4)
cdf(0.4)
```